# Windows FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x

I want to use `'os.path.join'` to open a file, the file exists, but I can not open it and get an error `"FileNotFoundError"`.

This is running python3.6, using PyCharm in Windows10.

The error is occur in this function:

```py
def get_encoder(model_name):
    with open(os.path.join('models', model_name, 'encoder.json'), 'r') as f:
        encoder = json.load(f)
```

The output is `' FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'models\ \345M\ \encoder.json'`

My file directory is `' ...\models\345M\encoder.json '`
The function is defined by `' ...\encode.py '`

[image: 20190519230831.png]

Comment: Can you check if the folder `models/model_name` exists before the join command? It looks like the ` models `folder is outside the src folder, and thus cannot be detected the way you current show.

Comment: Yes. The 'encode.py' also outside the src folder, I don't know what effect this will have.

Comment: Can you try this to debug: 

```if not os.path.exists(model_name):
         print(model_name + "does not exist")```

Your screenshot shows encode.py inside `src` folder.

Comment: I changed the screenshot to make it clearer.

Comment: But `encoder.py` (where your code appears to currently sit is still in the `src` folder?

Comment: I used that to debug, it can print ` 345M does not exist `

Comment: U are right, I made a mistake, is `encoder.py` not `encode.py`, but I don`t know how to fix the bug, please teach me, thank you！

Comment: Add the root folder to your path and you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem comes from not including the right root folder. Since the `encoder.py` file is inside the `src` folder and the path is searching for `models` inside of `src`.

The code should be:

```
def get_encoder(model_name):
    with open(os.path.join('..\\models', model_name, 'encoder.json'), 'r') as f:
        encoder = json.load(f)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: No,The bug still exists.`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../models\\345M\\encoder.json'`

Comment: I forgot you are on a Windows machine. Using the correct backslash should fix this. Let me know if the edited version works.

Comment: I print absolutized version of the pathname, it is in `D:\`, but my project is in `I:\`, so I changed the direction, it slove my problem.Thank you so much for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

I used `os.path.abspath` to print absolutized version of the pathname.It print `D:\Anaconda3\envs\...`.But my project is in `I:\`, so I use `os.chdir()` to change my directory and it works.